# Change the Option+R/L shortcuts to Control+R/L

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut

I would like to remap the Option+L/R shortcut on my Mac keyboard to Control+R/L. I don't want to use the modifier keys dialog because I only want to change these particular shortcuts.
Any help would be appreciated.
Bill

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, by R/L I mean the right arrow and left arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example below Option-L/R arrow does the same after adjusting the keycodes as Control-L/R arrow.

The previous behavior Option-L/R arrow (e.g opening/closing a folder in list view) is lost.

If you want a different behavior you have to modify/precise your answer.

To make this work you have to use a third party tool: Karabiner.

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <item>
         <name>Change Option L/R arrow to Control L/R arrow</name>
         <identifier>altlr2ctrllr</identifier>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL</autogen>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL</autogen>
     </item>
   </root>
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

---

And if you are really asking for "Option+L/R shortcut on my Mac keyboard to Control+R/L" - which can be read as alt-l to ctrl-r and alt-r to ctrl-l in contrary to the headline - then use

```
          <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL</autogen>
          <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL</autogen>
```

---

If you want the opposite (Control-L/R arrow does the same as Option-L/R arrow) use this snippet instead. The previous behavior of Control-L/R arrow is lost.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Change Control L/R arrow to Option L/R arrow</name>
    <identifier>ctrllr2altlr</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

---

If you want to swap ctrl-L/R-arrow with ctrl-L/R-arrow then use either both of the above keycode changes or this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Swap Control L/R arrow and Option L/R arrow</name>
    <identifier>swap_ctrllrarrow_altlrarrow</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_CONTROL, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Both your first and last code wont change the behaviour of ctrl-L/R. In both instances the cursor still moves to the far left and far right of the line. Option L/R behaves differently depending on the code: the first code doesnt change the behaviour, it still moves the cursor to the beginning of the previous or next word, while your last code disables option-R and changes option-L to switch to dashboard.

Comment: Which means that I still can't program Ctrl-L/R to do what I want, namely to move the cursor to the beginning of previous and next words respectively. I'm just wondering if Apple hasn't got some built-in protection of its own keyboard.

Comment: @BillR. Hmm the last and the second last do exactly what you want. In the last one (which is a new mod) ctrl-L/R-arrow behaves like alt-L/R-arrow and alt-L/R-arrow behaves like ctrl-L/R-arrow now. You have to disable all other mods made in private.xml in the Karabiner prefs though.

Comment: @klanomath do you have a solution for a [similar issue](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269844/re-assign-ctraltf-shortcut?noredirect=1#comment339036_269844) ? thanks - I don't know if this post is breaking 'stack rules' ...it's a related issue...anyway, I can remove it later on

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge of keyboard bindings is that it's difficult to do without installing third party applications. With that said, [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) (formerly KeyRemap4MacBook) provides a great way of customizing bindings easily, and should be able to do what you want.

Comment: I tried Karabiner and couldn't find these particular two shortcuts anywhere. I might be just missing it, so if anyone can confirm that it is possible in Karabiner and perhaps point to where I need to go to find them, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @BillR. That's quite possible. It may be possible to [edit the XML file](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) giving you greater control. Take a look and let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I looked at your suggestion to edit the XML file but I'm afraid its Greek to me. I'll need an 'average joe' solution for this one.

Comment: @BillR. Sorry, I'm afraid I don't know. I'll let you know if I think of anything.