# Re-assign ctr+alt+F shortcut

Tags: macos, shortcut

How can I eliminate the useless 
<kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> global shortcut (move cursor to the next word)? It's in conflict with another custom shortcut I really need.

(macOS Sierra 12.12.2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the Option+R/L shortcuts to Control+R/L](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225298/change-the-optionr-l-shortcuts-to-controlr-l).  While not an *exact* duplicate (differing key combos) the premise of the question and the answer are the same.

Comment: thanks for this link...however,  I couldn't find the shortcut I am talking about in 'karabiner', nor I have any idea of how to modify the .xml they talk about, to get the effect I want...

Comment: @jjrr Please add your system version! Because Sierra and Karabiner are still not compatible! Also: in which app(s) do you need the ctrl-alt-F shortcut to work differently? And: using a German keyboard layout the shortcut doesn't work at all. I just get a ƒ. Using the en_US layout it works though.

Comment: ah, too bad - I have macOS 10.12.2. I would like to remove  system-wide both 'alt+F'  (move one word to the right)  and 'crtl+F' (move one character to the right) , especially in safari

Comment: Seeing that's it's Sierra, I went ahead and retracted my close vote and edited the question with the detail.

Comment: Would it be easier to reassign the app's key command than try disable a system-wide shortcut that has no menu option?

Comment: @Tetsujin well, maybe...I also thought about that, but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: I'd need to know what app - but here's a generic explanation - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269851/85275

Comment: thanks for your link — as I said in a previous comment, it's primarily for safari, so far