# Shortcut to open/close sidebar in Notes app?

Tags: shortcut, notes.app

In Safari, you can press  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>⇧</kbd>  <kbd>L</kbd>  to open/close the sidebar. When pressing this shortcut in Notes however, it creates a list.

What's the shortcut in Apple's notes app to toggle the sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't actually call it a sidebar, they term it 'Folders'

It's in the View menu as Show or Hide Folders, with no default shortcut

You could make your own shortcut in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts >App Shortcuts - though you'd actually have to make two, for the different wording.
If you chose to re-use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd>  you would also have to reassign Checklist from the Format menu to something else before it will work.

Shown using a different key combo below for simplicity

[image]

[image]

Comment: To avoid re-assigning the checklist shortcut you could use 'ctrl + shift + L' which isn't used for anything in Notes, but is still so close to the shortcut that you're used to using in Safari that it should be fairly easy to remember. (Not to mention it's actually easier to press!)